# Cannot build for linux on windows

Tags: 3d

I'm using 2019.4.19f1 version unity, and i can't building project for linux[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might just be missing the linux build support modules

In Unity Hub go to

Installs > Click on the 3 dots for your unity version > Add Modules

Then check and add Linux build support. It looks like you're using mono so you'd install the mono module

[image]